# How to use rsync for Windows on both ends?

Tags: windows-10, git-bash, rsync

I install rsync for Windows through git-bash. If the remote end is Linux, it works fine. However, it does not work if the remote end is Windows. I install rsync on the remote end and test working as well, but it seems somehow it cannot locate its counterpart on the remote end.

```
$ rsync file user@host:
'rsync' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]
```

Note, ssh and scp between the two Windows work well.

Comment: https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/rsync-windows-10-1021.html could be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently, none of the methods described on the Internet satisfied my needs, so I came up with another one:

https://medium.com/@vitezslav.kot/two-way-file-synchronization-using-rsync-and-ssh-public-key-authentication-on-windows-c99323c7a308